# Combine SQL Insert INTO

Tags: sql, vba, insert, ms-access-2010

I am trying to combine 3 `SQL` statemnets in VBA so that they show up as one record in a table.  For some reason VBA throws a too few parameters error. Here is what my debug print statement outputs:

```
INSERT INTO Totals
            ([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES],[TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT],[TOTAL       SHOULD BE IMPORTED])
SELECT A.cnt,B.cnt,C.cnt
FROM   (SELECT Count([FORMULARY ID]) AS cnt
        FROM   VerifiedFormularies) AS A,
       (SELECT Count([FORMULARY ID]) AS cnt
        FROM   ImportMetricsIDs) AS B,
       (SELECT Count([FORMULARY ID]) AS cnt
        FROM   ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable
        WHERE  [IMPORT STATUS] = 'Yes') AS C
```

And here is my code:

```
totalVerified = "INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED]) " & _
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt " & _
"FROM ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM VerifiedFormularies " & _
") AS A " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
") as B " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable " & _
    "WHERE [IMPORT STATUS]= 'Yes' " & _
") AS C "
```

I have tried to debug it but was unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many spaces does this field name really contain? ... `[TOTAL       SHOULD BE IMPORTED]`

Comment: Does the query run when you run it by itself (both the `select` by itself and then with the `insert`)?  How many columns are in your `Totals` table?  Looks ok at first glance...

Comment: First of all, please try if SELECT statement works as you wish.

Comment: Instead of: **& _** use **& vbcr & _**

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. You missed last **)**

```
totalVerified = "INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED]) " & vbcr & _
"SELECT [TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED] " & vbcr & _
"FROM ( " & vbcr & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & vbcr & _
    "FROM VerifiedFormularies " & vbcr & _
") AS [TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], " & vbcr & _
"( " & vbcr & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & vbcr & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & vbcr & _
") AS [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], " & vbcr & _
"( " & vbcr & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & vbcr & _
    "FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable " & vbcr & _
    "WHERE [IMPORT STATUS]= 'Yes' " & vbcr & _
") AS [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED] " & vbcr & _
")"
```

I'd suggest to use the same names in query. Note, that data type must be the same!